# jQuery Mosaic Flow, images are not visible until I resize my browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

[Take a look at the images in this link](http://sapegin.github.io/jquery.mosaicflow/)

I'm building a similiar page using the same Mosaic Flow plugin, the only difference between my page and the example page above is that I'm fetching the images through AJAX.

**The problem:** The images are not visible after the ajax call. They only start to show when I resize my browser window or zoom in/out. The ajax call works fine, the images are retrieved and appended to the correct container element, and the Mosaic Flow runs correctly (minus the invisible part). Once I resize the browser window, the plugin works flawlessly, resizing and creating columns as it should, just like in the example link I provided

Here is my ajax code:

```
    var container = jQuery( "#container" );
    jQuery( "button#submit" ).on( "click", function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/ajax_getimages.php",
            success: function( data ){
                container.html( data );
            },
            complete: function(){
                jQuery( "#image-container" ).mosaicflow( { 
                    itemSelector: ".item", 
                    minItemWidth: 300 
                });
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

What causes this invisible behaviour, and why does it only occur when I use ajax to retrieve the images, and how I can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it helped in my case :).

```
var container = jQuery( "#container" );
jQuery( "button#submit" ).on( "click", function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/ajax_getimages.php",
        success: function( data ){
            container.html( data );
        },
        complete: function(){
            var mosaic = jQuery( "#image-container" ).mosaicflow( { 
                itemSelector: ".item", 
                minItemWidth: 300 
            });
           mosaic.mosaicflow('refill'); 
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```